# How to resolve com.facebook.android.*

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I have the following changes in my app gradle for facebook related development:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.0'
}
```

In one of my Fragment methods, I have these declarations:

```
public static Facebook facebook = null;
public static AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = null;
```

But there were compile errors because these classes are specified in
`com.facebook.android.*`

The imports in my app from mavenCentral for facebook do not include "android" in
the path, that is, `com.facebook.*` (where * does not include "android").

The imports from `mavenCentral` do not include `com.facebook.android.*`
How can I get `com.facebook.android.*`

Answer (score 0):

The com.facebook.android package was in old versions of the Facebook Android SDK (I think that in the 3.x versions). The current 4.x versions doesn't have that packages. You would either need to update your app to the new SDK version (recommended) or if you want to use what you have now, use the old 3.x versions.
Check out this, this is the [3.23.1 version](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/50e8000d765abca3417744eb8cadb2b4c002862c/facebook/src/com/facebook), which in fact shows the com.facebook.android package. This is the [4.0 version](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/752ea7b77a1779ed8b784dbd55a886cc00aeb8a6/facebook/src/com/facebook), which doesn't have the com.facebook.android package.